# SQL Server performance of copied database

Tags: sql-server, database, performance

I encountered some problems with SQL Server performance.

I have a daily process which is using 15GB size database. I'm executing a lot of scripts.

The thing is, the first step is to copy original database, and work on this copy. And what is surprising me, is that queries on this copy are executing few times slower than on the original one.

I'm not an expert in databases, so basically I don't really know what might be the reason.

To compare:

Query "A" took:

- 50 seconds on original database
- 600 seconds on copied database

Thank you for your interest,
dejvid

Comment: Are you copying everything over to the copied database including indexes (Compare the [execution plans](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to see if there are differences)? Are you running the query on each database a few times to get an average? The first time you run the query on the copied database you will need to compile the plan and may need to read data into memory - Compare the [IO statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx) to see if the reads are comparable.

Comment: Just do a backup and restore via script.